# Input box in foreach not binding correctly in knockout, only in IE

Tags: foreach, knockout.js

I have seen some people witm similar problems, but no solutions work. I have a viewmodel looking like

```
var House = function() {
    this.houseName = ko.observable("");
    this.reports = ko.observableArray([]);

    this.addReport = function() { this.reports.push(new Report) }.bind(this);
}
```

and "reports" gets filled - at House.addReport() - with

```
var Report = function() {
     this.reportname = ko.observable("");
     this.sensor_id = ko.observable(0);
}
```

The HTML looks like (simplified)

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: houseName">
<div data-bind="foreach: reports">
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: reportname"><select data-bind="value: sensor_id" />
</div>
```

So, to the problem. When I fill in houseName, outside of the foreach, the model changes OK (I continually see it in a debug DIV). When I trigger the addReport method, the UI does as it's told and adds a textbox and a select. But only a change of the select actually changes the model - NOT a change of the textbox! Strangest of all, it seems to work in IE but not in Chrome.

Most probably a miss by me that gets behind-the-scenes treatment by IE - but what is the bug?

**EDIT**
This [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/gZC5k/) seems to aim at almost exactly the same goal - without my problem.

**EDIT reloaded** It doesn't work in Firefox either. However, it seems to work OK in JSFiddle!

Comment: Have you tried to add `valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'` in your text's input data-bind?

Comment: No. I don't understand why the other fields auto-update when I leave them, just not textboxes inside "foreach". I don't have to see the changes instantly, as long as they hit the model.

Comment: If it works in the fiddle, you must have some other code that is breaking. Do you see any errors in your javascript console?

Comment: You oversimplified your example. Please update it with _enough_ code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: You will want to use `<select data-bind="value: sensor_id"></select>` rather than a self-closing tag for that type of element, otherwise you will run into problems.  I don't think that I have necessarily seen problems with `input` tags, but typically you would do a self-closing tag in that case `<input />`

Comment: Sorry, that was probably one of the aforementioned oversimplifications. But those fields actually get filled when I load FROM the database, the problem is the model not getting updated when I change the form. The INPUT tags outside the foreach (which work) look exactly like the ones inside (which don't).
There are no JS errors in the debugger whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

My apologies - Jeff's analysis of not reproducing enough code was correct (it would have been too much to reproduce, here!)
Anyway, my error was that deep down in my code (even before Knockout came into the pic), I handled the "change" event to know when the form was dirty - thereby hijacking an event important to Knockout's business!
Be warned, others who may think of the same solution!
I see that RP Niemeyer has addressed the problem [here](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/05/creating-smart-dirty-flag-in-knockoutjs.html).